# Remove identical entries that have true value on a column in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a table that kinda looks like this:

```
WebDocumentId   To remove
675082          0
675082          0
675082          0
675083          0
675083          1
675083          0
675083          0
675083          0
675085          1
675085          0
675087          0
675087          0
675087          1
675087          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
```

My aim is to somehow remove all the identical entries for which 1 appears at least once in the 'to remove' column. A simple VLOOKUP on a third column would have worked if 1 was the first value of an id.

Summing up, the final table should look like this:

```
WebDocumentId   To remove
675082          0
675082          0
675082          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
675089          0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just filter on the 1's and delete the rows?

Comment: But that would only remove the row where an entry has 1 on the 'to remove' column. I would like all the identical ids for which 1 appears at least once to be removed.

Comment: You're right - sorry, I didn't read carefully enough

Answer (score 0):

See below. Some important notes about this code:

1. It's going to be very slow if your list is long. It creates a list
   of all items with a '1' in column B and then loops through that list
   for **every** entry in column A.
2. It doesn't address potential duplicates in column B. In other words
   if you have a document that is marked "to remove" twice then it will
   check twice which is inefficient.
3. It doesn't handle blanks in column A.
4. **It deletes the entire row and not just columns A & B. If you have
   data in columns C or greater, that data will be deleted. Please use
   caution.**

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub RemoveEntries()


       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

       Dim startRow As Long
       startRow = 2

       Dim endRow As Long
       endRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

       ' make a list of IDs to delete
       Dim rowsToDelete() As String
       Dim arraySize As Long
       arraySize = -1  ' note this isn't zero

       Dim row As Long
       For row = startRow To endRow
           If ws.Cells(row, 2).Value = 1 Then
               arraySize = arraySize + 1
               ReDim Preserve rowsToDelete(arraySize)
               rowsToDelete(arraySize) = ws.Cells(row, 1)
           End If
       Next row

       ' delete the rows
       Dim checkRow As Long
       For row = endRow To startRow Step -1 ' note that we're starting at the bottom
          For checkRow = 0 To UBound(rowsToDelete)
           If ws.Cells(row, 1).Value = rowsToDelete(checkRow) Then
               ws.Rows(row).Delete
               Exit For
           End If
          Next checkRow
       Next row

   End Sub
   ```